# when I try to install ubuntu in dual boot it will not display partition of my windows so what is the problem?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning

when I try to install Ubuntu 14.04 along with my windows 8.1 in dual boot it doesn't show me the partitions of my windows 8.1 and a free block that i had created.
please give me the solution.

Comment: I actually had the same problem, when trying to install Ubuntu on a friends computer with Windows 8. Windows installations disks can see the partitions fine, but the ubuntu installer can't see anything.

Answer (score 0):

1st step --->  you have to separate the free space in the Hard disk
 2th step ----> In that free partition you have to install the Ubuntu 14.04 version
3th step--->  if didnt show the free block u have to shrink the free space that show the unused space

Comment: ya i did all of that but it doesn't show me that free block.